# For loop with multiple ranges ? VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to do a for loop with multiple ranges, but i can't find a way with the "set" range as can you help me ?

Here my code with one range:

```
Dim mycell As Range
Dim myrange As Range
    
Set myrange = src.Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("G1:500")
    
For Each mycell In myrange
        data = mycell.Value
Next mycell
```

but how can I do with two ranges at the same times in the for loop and after one range in a if condition and another in another if condition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to loop over two distinct (same-size) ranges then you can use a `For...Next` loop:

```vb
Dim i As Long, data1, data2
Dim myrange1 As Range, myrange2 As Range
    
Set myrange1 = src.Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("G1:G500")
Set myrange2 = src.Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("J1:J500")
    
For i = 1 to myrange1.Cells.Count
    data1 = myrange1.Cells(i).Value
    data2 = myrange2.Cells(i).Value
    'do something with data1 and data2
Next i
```

Comment: This loop starts with `For i` but uses `Next mycell`, is that intentional? Also, the ranges set seem to have a columns-issue.

Comment: I think the `src.Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("G1").Resize(500,1)` syntax is more maintainable as you can change the size of the table without having to manipulate strings **and** you can move the top left cell around with only changing the `"G1"`.

Comment: Agreed but it's just an example for the OP's use, so I followed their notation...  If I were doing this I'd probably loop over the full table rows and pick the values from the row.